# How to add newline and concatenation in ternary conditional operator ? : in c++

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I want to rewrite this code using ternary conditional operator ? : in c++ but I can't add new line (that is expressed by endl here) or concatenate the empty string

```
if (n % 10 == 0) {cout << n << endl;}
else {cout << n << " ";}
```

when is use this code

```
cout << (n % 10 == 0 ? n + "\n" : n + " ");
```

it doesn't produce the correct output
it produces "@" (without double quotes) if I assign 10 to n and produce ",@" if I assign 11 to n

Comment: But why? The first code is much more readable.

Comment: the problem is not the ternary, but adding string literals. I wonder how you can compile it without getting some warnings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on acraig5075's answer (C++ has no operator+ to concatenate a string to an integer, though it could be written), one could

`cout << n << (n % 10 == 0 ? "\n" : " ");`

Makes it clearer it prints n, then either a space or a new line, depending on n's value.

Comment: Whilst I really would like it if this worked, it doesn't. `std::endl` and `" "` don't have a common type. Perhaps `"\n"`?

Comment: I got this error
"cannot determine which instance of function template "std::endl" is intended"

Comment: My fault for not trying to compile it, replaced endl in my answer with "\n".

Comment: Which you probably wanted to do anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a string literal to an integer. You should instead first build the desired output string by, for example, using [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Change

```
cout << (n % 10 == 0 ? n + "\n" : n + " ");
```

To

```
cout << (n % 10 == 0 ? std::to_string(n) + "\n" : std::to_string(n) + " ");
```

Comment: Or cout << n << (n % 10 == 0 ? endl : " ");

Comment: @UriRaz Agreed, infinitely better, make it an answer and I'll upvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << n << (n % 10 ? " ": endl);  // if remainder is not zero put " "
```

Comment: add context to prevent bot flagging and removal. (End of LQ Post Review).